# PDO does not recognize column with special character

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create an application with SimpleMVC (PHP Framework) and in the database there is a column with the name "**contraseña**".
When trying to make any query in this column, the PDO returns this error:

```
SQLSTATE [HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

There is how to make the PDO recognize special characters?

Controller:

```
$servidor = array(
 'cuenta' => $usuario,
 'contraseña' => $senha,
 'ipRegistro' => $ip,
 'apodo' => $apelido
);
$this->_model->insert_server($servidor);
```

Model:

```
public function insert_server($data) {
 $this->_db->insert("cuentas",$data);
}
```

Link to the SimpleMVC Framework: [PHP Framework - SimpleMVC](http://simplemvcframework.com/php-framework)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the column name in backticks (`\``)?

Comment: @Fly - that's probably the solution - should post it as such.

Comment: Show your `_db->insert` or `->update` code. If that framework is just transposing the array names literally onto `:placeholders`, there's little chance to fix it yourself though. File a bug report; and use only English column names in l' future :/

Comment: That is not a PDO problem, it is the person who create the column with a special character. @Fly already give you the answer you need. Just put on your query on that field backticks as select \`contraseña\` from ....

Comment: Fred, Already UTF8. 
mario, Done. 
@JorgeCampos, I can't change column name... (You are Brazillian?).

Comment: Why can't you change column name?

Comment: @ChrisBorn Yes I'm :)

Comment: Thanks for personal support. I could not change the name because another service was using the same. But the administrator of the DB get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the column bame in backticks, like so:

```
$servidor = array(
 'cuenta' => $usuario,
 '`contraseña`' => $senha,
 'ipRegistro' => $ip,
 'apodo' => $apelido
);
```

Might be something worth mentioning to the SimpleMVC developers.

Comment: Hey @fly I think it worth to mention the MySql docs about the special chars. Here: [9.2 Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) second paragraph. +1 for your answer anyway :)